# ASP.NET MVC Razor - Uploading File, HttpPostedFileBase always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, httppostedfilebase, enctype

Well, this is weird.
I'm doing everything as I massively found on the web, but still doesn't work.
I want to upload a file, so in the View I put:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
<input type="submit" value="Importa" />
}
```

and this is Home/Import:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] // or [HttpPost], nothing changes
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Inside Import");
   if (uploadFile == null)
       Debug.WriteLine("null");
   // Verify that the user selected a file
   if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("Valid File");
      ...
   }
}
```

and it always prints *Inside Import* + *null*. So I'm sure I call the right Controller Action but it always receive a null HttpPostedFileBase.

Does anyone have advice for it or have already found (and solved) this kind of problem?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried it just using the HTML form tag instead of the Razor helper?

Comment: I did billions of things trying to figure it out, so I don't remember very well...but I think I tried it! And with no results. I'm going to try again, though. So, stay tuned and you'll have news from me, thanks!

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work using the HTML form tag, neither. So I guess I also tried this before ;) Really can't realize why it doesn't work to me, while everyone else does.

Comment: have you used a web debugging tool (FireBug/Chrome Developer/Fiddler) to check the content of the posted data?  You should be able to see a request payload with name="uploadFile"

Comment: ps I tested your code and it posted data fine in Chrome, uploadFile was not null

Comment: I know, it's theorically perfect: it has the correct enctype attribute, it has the input type file name equals to the name of the action parameter... it's copy-pasted from a for-all working file upload form. But for my site (no matter what the browser) it isn't working. Are there known issues with the use of it with jQuery Mobile? Who knows...

Comment: ah didn't realise you were using jQuery mobile, see this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-seems-to-clobber-ability-to-upload-files-via-forms

Comment: Sorry, haven't specified it, my bad! I answered my question when I realized that could be the problem, the linked topic explains well the situation! Thanks for illuminating me! ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the problem.  You have to put the html attribute "@data_ajax = "false" " in the view, near the enctype one.
So, if you are using jQuery Mobile, be sure to write

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
```

Hope this will help someone!

Comment: You should have specified in the question that you are using jquery mobile. I added the tag to your question by the way.

Comment: Does not solve my issue... when I remove JQuery library from the page it works fine...Any suggestion?